# What do you call resuscitating methods like mouth to mouth?

Tags: word-request

What do you call resuscitating methods like mouth to mouth? Is there a better term? I am sure there is a better term for this, but I don't remember what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia offers these synonyms:

> It is also known as expired air resuscitation (EAR), expired air ventilation (EAV), rescue breathing, or colloquially the kiss of life. It was introduced as a life saving measure in 1950.[5]

It is also referred to there as "a method of insufflation".

[Wikipedia *mouth-to-mouth resuscitation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouth-to-mouth_resuscitation)

Answer (score 0):

I think the common and widely-recognized term is "mouth-to-mouth resuscitation". Sometimes just "mouth-to-mouth" for short. As in, "The lifeguard revived the drowning victim by giving him mouth-to-mouth."

When you say "methods LIKE" ... I don't know you would consider other methods LIKE mouth-to-mouth resuscitation. Perhaps "methods of resuscitation"?

Answer (score 0):

CPR is a commonly used although incorrect synonym for it:

> Cardiopulmonary resuscitation (CPR) is an emergency procedure that combines chest compressions **often with artificial ventilation** in an effort to manually preserve intact brain function until further measures are taken to restore spontaneous blood circulation and breathing in a person who is in cardiac arrest. It is recommended in those who are unresponsive with no breathing or abnormal breathing, for example, agonal respirations.[1]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiopulmonary_resuscitation

Again, this isn't a technically correct, but it is extremely common to see CPR and mouth-to-mouth used interchangeably.  I've never heard the terms in the accepted answer ever used by non-medical professionals.